# What does `ls --directory` stand for?

Tags: command-line, ls

In my Ubuntu version the man ls has the next info about --directory:

```
list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links
```

So I'm a little confused how it works.
I used the command `ls --directory` and I expected a list with all directories but instead I got `.`

So what exactly does `ls --directory` or `ls -d` do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ man ls
...
-d, --directory
              list directories themselves, not their contents
```

The current directory is represented as `.` so that's what `ls -d` is listing.

The directories inside the current directory are contents of the directory, and are therefore not shown with this option.

I use the `-d` option in an alias to display hidden files and directories

```
alias l.='ls -dC .* --color'
```

Without `-d`, this will list out the contents of the hidden directories too, which isn't what I want.

Another use for it is when I want to see metadata of a directory using the `-l` option, not its contents:

```
$ ls -ld playground
drwxr-xr-x 72 zanna zanna 12288 Mar  1 23:10 playground
```

If you want a list of directories in the current directory you can use

```
ls -d */
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `ls` only with `-d` is almost useless. It gives information about the directory itself. It does not list its contents.

That is why you do not see a list of directories. The directories that you expected to see are the "contents" of the current directory

If you run simply `ls -d` it shows the current directory by `.`.

If makes sense to run it with other keys like `-l`.

`ls -ld` will show permissions of the current directory.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ ls -ld
drwxrwxr-x 1 pilot6 pilot6 2570 Mar  4 12:14 .
```

You can also see permissions of any other directory like

```
ls -ld /bin

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ ls -ld /bin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2584 Feb 25 15:19 /bin
```

If you run `ls -l` without `-d` you will have the list of all permissions for files and folders in the current directory. If you do not need it, that's a good example for `ls -ld` usage.

You can list directories in the current one by

```
ls -d */
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `ls -d` by itself is fairly useless because without a parameter it always returns `.`. After you specify a parameter it makes sense though. For example if your user name is `rick` and you want to see all the directories in your home use:

```
$ ls -d /home/rick/*/
/home/rick/AAC/        /home/rick/EnhanceIO/         /home/rick/silentcast/
/home/rick/assembly/   /home/rick/EnhanceIO-master/  /home/rick/Templates/
/home/rick/bin/        /home/rick/log/               /home/rick/test/
/home/rick/Desktop/    /home/rick/Music/             /home/rick/tmpe/
/home/rick/Documents/  /home/rick/Pictures/          /home/rick/Videos/
/home/rick/Downloads/  /home/rick/Public/
```

Answer (score 5):

Let me explain with examples:

1. `ls`: list contents of a directory
2. `ls -d` or `ls --directory`: list directories themselves, not their contents

Examples:

```
ls -d android-sdk-linux/

# result
android-sdk-linux/

ls android-sdk-linux/

# result
add-ons  build-tools  platforms  platform-tools  SDK Readme.txt  temp  tools
```

Your case of `ls -d` this says to list *only show me* the directory I am in not its content (i.e. `.` in Linux terms), so the result is: `.`.

But if you had said: `ls`, then you will see all that is present in the current directory `.`.

Answer (score 4):

`ls -d` list directories them self instead of their content. Files are listed as normal. Look into `man ls`to se description of all options.

`.` is the directory it self, the same you use when running a command from current directory, `./runscript.sh`

`..` is parent directory, the parent to the current directore, as in `cd ..` to move at step up in directory hieracy