# What does ls -al .* command return?

Tags: command-line, ls

Does it show hidden file names inside all directories? Or just the current directory (including any directory inside it)? I cannot understand why `ls -ld .*` returns different results (it shows hidden files and directories ONLY in current directory, not showing files inside any other directory inside it)? Also What does `-d` do alone (`ls -d`)?

Comment: For `-d` see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/889540/what-does-ls-directory-do)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls -al .*` shows the contents of all directories in the current directory whose names begin with `.` (ie all those matching the shell glob `.*`)

In Bash, the `.*` glob resolves to `.` and `..` as well. Since `.` represents the current directory, and `..` the parent directory, the contents of both of these directories, including any hidden files and directories, are shown too.<sup>1</sup>

`.*` also catches hidden files in the current directory, but they are listed anyway as contents of `.`

As explained in [What does `ls --directory` stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889540/what-does-ls-directory-do) the `-d` flag causes the directories themselves to be displayed, instead of their contents.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>this is also the case in dash, which is the shell symlinked to `sh` in Ubuntu. However, other shells, including zsh and mksh, behave more intuitively and don't include `.` and `..` when expanding `.*`. It is also worth noting that, while most commands will operate on `..` and `.` when they are included in a `.*` glob (including `chmod` and `chown` - you can really mess up your system with those), the `rm` command will helpfully fail by design to do so.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It will list down all the files + directories including hidden files/directories in the current directory along with the files starting with `.` in their names.

`ls` means listing of the directories along with files in the current directory.
`a` denotes all the files in the directory, both hidden and not.
`l` denotes the long listing of information about files+directory with their permissions and last updated time.
`.*` denotes all the hidden files in the current directory starting with `.` in their name.

Comment: Edited. I have Explained in detail now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It will return all the hidden files, or files starting with `.` in that directory. To view all files (including hidden) in a directory, use `ls -al`